# Magento 2 Get Error after add custom attribute in product

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, catalog, custom-attributes

I use following code to add custom attribute in product magento 2

```
<?php

namespace Marketplace\Attribute\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

private $eavSetupFactory;

public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}


public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{

    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
      \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
      'storevendor_id',
      [
        'type' => 'int',
        'backend' => '',
        'frontend' => '',
        'label' => 'Sample Atrribute',
        'input' => '',
        'class' => '',
        'source' => '',
        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => false,
        'default' => '',
        'searchable' => false,
        'filterable' => false,
        'comparable' => false,
        'visible_on_front' => false,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'unique' => false,
        'apply_to' => ''
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

but when after install it I got error when open detail product page in admin page

[image]

is there something wrong with my script ?

Comment: Please keep  'input' => 'text',

Comment: Please use this tool which is very easy and simple to create a custom attribute  and it will help you lot http://prntscr.com/g74z8a

Comment: https://mage2gen.com/

Comment: thank for reply @NagarajuKasa, I will try first this app

Comment: Please get with your comments and doubts so that i will assist you accordingly thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with this code in local magento 2

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'review_data',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Review Data',
                'input' => 'text',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => 1,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'default' => null,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => true,
                'apply_to' => '',
                'system' => 1,
                'group' => 'General',
                'option' => array('values' => array(""))
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, it works. I just know if there is generator extension for magento2, your post answer is same with the output generate from [link](https://mage2gen.com). So I deleted my old custom attribute and follow your script, now I'm not getting this error again.. :)

Comment: Glad to hear please raise upvote so that it will help you for other developers also thanks

Comment: Ok  I will raise upvote tomorrow.  Because today, my dailly voted has reached limit :D